# count inside a loop?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to select all products:

```
select id, data, name from products where user= ?
```

Inside a while I print this results:

```
while{
product name, data
...
}
```

the problem is, I need to count the sells each product has.
so inside the while I have another select, just to count:

```
     while{
select count(id) from sells where product_id = id
        product name, data, sells count
        ...
        }
```

So my question is simple, can I avoid this count inside the loop? can I count just once in the first select without group my results?

Comment: When asking a question actual code beats pseudo code every time...

Comment: first do the query. Then depending on the results you iterate. Do not place a sql query inside a while loop.

Comment: @CodeGodie can you give me an example?

Comment: this is a good [example](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp) Notice how they first make the query, then depending on those results you iterate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select products.id, data, name, count(sells.id) as sell_count
from products 
left join sells on sells.product_id=products.id 
where user= ?
group by products.id
```